# Visual studio 2013 view project in browser gives internal server error

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013

I am new with Visual studio 2013 and I am currently working on two projects started by another developer. With one project the view option works fine using IIS Express, but the second one gives me error 500 with the below details...

"HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error. The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid."

"Config Error: Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'"

```
Config Source:
<customHeaders>
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
```

Hope somebody knows about an error like this and how I can solve it. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect IIS is already sending an Access-Control-Allow-Headers by default and that is blowing up.

Typically when setting custom headers one usually does a prophalactic removal first:

```
<customHeaders>
<remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
<remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
</customHeaers>
```

This insures your app works no matter what happened upstream in configuration.

Comment: Thanx... Only now I am getting another error "This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false"."

<security>
<access sslFlags="None" />
<requestFiltering>

Comment: Sounds like it is from a different section of the config but the issue is you are changing something the admin isn't allowing to be changed -- specifically that security.access.sslFlags value. You'll need to take it up with those guys.

Comment: I fixed the issue together with the former developer. By using visual studio 2012

Comment: Or more likely trying it in a different environment which didn't have these issues, nothing you had ran into has anything to do with Visual Studio.